# JS arrays 3 deep getting lost

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Learing JS by game. and of course the simplist is a clicker :-)
OK, so I have had lots of help with this, but the array section is just not sinking in. JS arrays do not work like arrays I am used to. two part question:
1. Why does the following code keep saying `weaponlevelIfo[0]` undefined, when it is defined? Please explain your answer, don't just correct mine LOL
2. I am more interesting in populating the code at runtime

As stated, all the research I am coming across as well as videos, talk about static data, i.e. it is put in at programing level, not run time.

I have had a really patient community person that has tried to help me understand JS arrays, but I must be blind as I am not seeing it. I can do in in other language just fine. but JS? nope.

```
// produces weaponLevelNfo[weaponId][level][cost] and [goldperclick]
// weapon, level 1-9, cost/goldperclick on each level
var weaponLevelNfo = new Array(14); // Outter array comprised of weapons 0-14
function initGame() {

    for (let i=0; i <= weaponLevelNfo.length; i++) {

        weaponLevelNfo[i] = new Array(9); // create leves array under weaponid array
        for (let j = 0; j < weaponLevelNfo[i].length; j++) {    
            // loop through each 9 levels changing as needed
            weaponLevelNfo[i][j] = new Array(2); // create an object for readability


        }
    }

}
initGame();// added - forgot to add this in the original post (sorry)
    weaponLevelNfo[0][0][2]=3;
    console.log(weaponLevelNfo[0][0][2]);
// always gives me weaponLevelNfo[0] not defined
```

I prefer the results to be as such

```
weaponLevelNfo[x][y].cost,
weaponLevelNfo[x][y].incomePerClick,
```

but am quite happy with

```
weaponLevelNfo[x][y][z],
weaponLevelNfo[x][y][z],
```

But as you can see from the code, assigning them direct or at runtime, I get the not defined error

What is missing to allow me to assign these at run time?

Comment: You never called `initGame`. Make sure to call it before using references like `weaponLevelNfo[0][0][2]`.

Comment: Opps forgot to put that. goes into some endless loop and locks my browser tab

Comment: So has your question changed then?

Comment: `i <= weaponLevelNfo.length` should be `i < weaponLevelNfo.length`. Indeed, if you run the loop with `i` equal to `weaponLevelNfo.length` it will add an element to the array, so its length increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- You need to call `initGame` to create all those subarrays, otherwise `weaponLevelNfo[0]` is not defined and so `weaponLevelNfo[0][0]` will trigger the error you get.
- Your outer loop performs one iteration too many (`<=`). Change:

  ```
  for (let i=0; i <= weaponLevelNfo.length; i++) {
  ```

  by

  ```
  for (let i=0; i < weaponLevelNfo.length; i++) {
  ```

  Without that change, the last iteration is actually *adding* an element to the array in slot `i`, and so the length of the array increases... the loop becomes infinit.

Note that there are shorter ways to define such a nested array. For instance:

```
var weaponLevelNfo = Array.from({length:14}, () => Array.from({length:9}, () => [0, 0]));
```

Comment: I cant see it, those 2 "for" loops look exactly the same. Love the short cut, but let me get a grasp on the basics LOL

Comment: oops just saw it the "=", ok I correct that, but still undefined error. I'll take a look at the shortcut

Comment: OK, shortcut version works perfect. now just need to look into it and find out why so I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array in javascript with `new Array(2)` this is an array with two positions. In this example (`new Array(2)`), you can access it at index 0 and index 1. Consider the following:

```
var newArr = new Array(2);
```

You can then access the two positions by the following:

```
var position1 = newArr[0];
var position2 = newArr[1];
```

So when you try this:

```
var position = newArr[2];
```

This will throw an undefined exception.

You can change the end of your example code to this:

```
weaponLevelNfo[0][0][1]=3;
console.log(weaponLevelNfo[0][0][1]);
```

Comment: what you said makes sense. however, my code should be within the array limits that was set. first array 14, second array9 and last array 2, so 0,0,0 should give me 3 (in the OP ).  Is there a limit I missed in my code? I might have missed it.

Comment: your last line, where you said it is throwing an undefined error. you have this: `weaponLevelNfo[0][0][2]=3; console.log(weaponLevelNfo[0][0][2]);` that last '2' is outside the bounds of the `new Array(2);` @JakeStone

Comment: omg your right - that should be a "1" - old school base 1 arrays LOL, Even years later when I got into the 0 based, I still forced 1 base. Just took awhile to count like a computer vs human.(yes I know that could be a debate in itself) - thats for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

You define array with two elements `Array(2)` with indexes 0 and 1 but you use index 2.

To initialize multidimensional array filled by zeros (if not remove `.fill(0)`) use

```
[...Array(14)].map(x=>[...Array(9)].map(y=>Array(2).fill(0)));
```

```js
let a=[...Array(14)].map(x=>[...Array(9)].map(y=>Array(2).fill(0)));

a[13][8][1]=3;

console.log('Last element value:',a[13][8][1]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```